# Relative Strength Index

Tags: algorithm, swift

I am calculating a relative strength index.

I took the calculations quite literally so I am sure everything's correct but now it is time to optimize the code and take it down to fewer variables.

The data is obtained from an API:

```
if let marketData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
            print(marketData.data[0].open)
            completion(marketData, nil)
}
```

and:

```
fetchData() { items, error in
guard let items = items,
    error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
}

let otherObject = calculateRSI()

otherObject.items = items
otherObject.calculateRSI()
```

}

Here is the struct:

```
    struct Level: Codable {
    let time: Double
    let close: Double
    let high: Double
    let low: Double
    let open: Double
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let data: [Level]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "Data"
    }
}
```

How would you do it? I tried to loop through an array but I'm struggling with incrementing the `data[x]` number...

```
    func calculateRSI()
{
    // Upward Movements and Downward Movements
    let upwardMovement1 = items.data[1].close > items.data[0].close ? (items.data[1].close - items.data[0].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement1 = items.data[1].close < items.data[0].close ? (items.data[0].close - items.data[1].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement2 = items.data[2].close > items.data[1].close ? (items.data[2].close - items.data[1].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement2 = items.data[2].close < items.data[1].close ? (items.data[1].close - items.data[2].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement3 = items.data[3].close > items.data[2].close ? (items.data[3].close - items.data[2].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement3 = items.data[3].close < items.data[2].close ? (items.data[2].close - items.data[3].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement4 = items.data[4].close > items.data[3].close ? (items.data[4].close - items.data[3].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement4 = items.data[4].close < items.data[3].close ? (items.data[3].close - items.data[4].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement5 = items.data[5].close > items.data[4].close ? (items.data[5].close - items.data[4].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement5 = items.data[5].close < items.data[4].close ? (items.data[4].close - items.data[5].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement6 = items.data[6].close > items.data[5].close ? (items.data[6].close - items.data[5].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement6 = items.data[6].close < items.data[5].close ? (items.data[5].close - items.data[6].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement7 = items.data[7].close > items.data[6].close ? (items.data[7].close - items.data[6].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement7 = items.data[7].close < items.data[6].close ? (items.data[6].close - items.data[7].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement8 = items.data[8].close > items.data[7].close ? (items.data[8].close - items.data[7].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement8 = items.data[8].close < items.data[7].close ? (items.data[7].close - items.data[8].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement9 = items.data[9].close > items.data[8].close ? (items.data[9].close - items.data[8].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement9 = items.data[9].close < items.data[8].close ? (items.data[8].close - items.data[9].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement10 = items.data[10].close > items.data[9].close ? (items.data[10].close - items.data[9].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement10 = items.data[10].close < items.data[9].close ? (items.data[9].close - items.data[10].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement11 = items.data[11].close > items.data[10].close ? (items.data[11].close - items.data[10].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement11 = items.data[11].close < items.data[10].close ? (items.data[10].close - items.data[11].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement12 = items.data[12].close > items.data[11].close ? (items.data[12].close - items.data[11].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement12 = items.data[12].close < items.data[11].close ? (items.data[11].close - items.data[12].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement13 = items.data[13].close > items.data[12].close ? (items.data[13].close - items.data[12].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement13 = items.data[13].close < items.data[12].close ? (items.data[12].close - items.data[13].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement14 = items.data[14].close > items.data[13].close ? (items.data[14].close - items.data[13].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement14 = items.data[14].close < items.data[13].close ? (items.data[13].close - items.data[14].close) : 0
    let upwardMovement15 = items.data[15].close > items.data[14].close ? (items.data[15].close - items.data[14].close) : 0
    let downwardMovement15 = items.data[15].close < items.data[14].close ? (items.data[14].close - items.data[15].close) : 0

    // Average Upward Movements and Average Downward Movements
    let averageUpwardMovement1 = (upwardMovement1 + upwardMovement2 + upwardMovement3 + upwardMovement4 + upwardMovement5 + upwardMovement6 + upwardMovement7 + upwardMovement8 + upwardMovement9 +   upwardMovement10 + upwardMovement11 + upwardMovement12 + upwardMovement13 + upwardMovement14) / 14
    let averageDownwardMovement1 = (downwardMovement1 + downwardMovement2 + downwardMovement3 + downwardMovement4 + downwardMovement5 + downwardMovement6 + downwardMovement7 + downwardMovement8 + downwardMovement9 + downwardMovement10 + downwardMovement11 + downwardMovement12 + downwardMovement13 + downwardMovement14) / 14

    let averageUpwardMovement2 = ((averageUpwardMovement1 * (14 - 1) + upwardMovement15) / 14)
    let averageDownwardMovement2 = ((averageDownwardMovement1 * (14 - 1) + downwardMovement15) / 14)

    // Relative Strength
    let relativeStrength1 = averageUpwardMovement1 / averageDownwardMovement1
    let relativeStrength2 = averageUpwardMovement2 / averageDownwardMovement2

    // Relative Strength Index
    let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 1))
    let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 1))

    // Relative Strength Index Average
    let rsiAverage = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2

    print("Relative Strength Index =", rsiAverage)

}
```

`let array = [items]` would be the full API data array from which I could increment I guess?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/183875/4) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would separate the calculations from the I/O and change the
function signature to

```
func calculateRSI(data: [Data]) -> Double {
    // ...    
    return rsiAverage
}
```

where `Data` is your data type containing a `close` property (which I
assume to be of type `Double`).

The next step is to define the up/downward movements as *arrays*
and to use a for-loop:

```
// Upward Movements and Downward Movements
var upwardMovements: [Double] = []
var downwardMovements: [Double] = []
for idx in 0..<15 {
    upwardMovements.append(data[idx + 1].close > data[idx].close ? data[idx + 1].close - data[idx].close : 0)
    downwardMovements.append(data[idx + 1].close > data[idx].close ? data[idx + 1].close - data[idx].close : 0)
}
```

The difference calculation  can be simplified by using the `max()` function:

```
for idx in 0..<15 {
    let diff =  data[idx + 1].close - data[idx].close
    upwardMovements.append(max(diff, 0))
    downwardMovements.append(max(-diff, 0))
}
```

Or use [`zip`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) to iterate over adjacent data values in parallel:

```
for (prev, now) in zip(data, data.dropFirst()) {
    let diff = now.close - prev.close
    upwardMovements.append(max(diff, 0))
    downwardMovements.append(max(-diff, 0))
}
```

Adding all elements in an sequence is conveniently done with the
[`reduce`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2907677-reduce) method, here we can apply it to an array [*slice:*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice)

```
// Average Upward Movements and Average Downward Movements
let averageUpwardMovement1 = upwardMovements[0..<14].reduce(0, +) / 14
let averageDownwardMovement1 = downwardMovements[0..<14].reduce(0, +) / 14

let averageUpwardMovement2 = ((averageUpwardMovement1 * (14 - 1) + upwardMovements[14]) / 14)
let averageDownwardMovement2 = ((averageDownwardMovement1 * (14 - 1) + downwardMovements[14]) / 14)
```

Finally you should define constants for the integer literals `14` and `15`, e.g.

```
let period = 14
```

or derive it from `data.count`, i.e. the number of given values.

Putting it all together, the function could look like this:

```
func calculateRSI(data: [Data]) -> Double {

    let period = data.count - 2

    // Upward Movements and Downward Movements
    var upwardMovements: [Double] = []
    var downwardMovements: [Double] = []

    for (prev, now) in zip(data, data.dropFirst()) {
        let diff = now.close - prev.close
        upwardMovements.append(max(diff, 0))
        downwardMovements.append(max(-diff, 0))
    }

    // Average Upward Movements and Average Downward Movements
    let averageUpwardMovement1 = upwardMovements[0..<period].reduce(0, +) / Double(period)
    let averageDownwardMovement1 = downwardMovements[0..<period].reduce(0, +) / Double(period)

    let averageUpwardMovement2 = (averageUpwardMovement1 * Double(period - 1) + upwardMovements[period]) / Double(period)
    let averageDownwardMovement2 = (averageDownwardMovement1 * Double(period - 1) + downwardMovements[period]) / Double(period)

    // Relative Strength
    let relativeStrength1 = averageUpwardMovement1 / averageDownwardMovement1
    let relativeStrength2 = averageUpwardMovement2 / averageDownwardMovement2

    // Relative Strength Index
    let rSI1 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength1 + 1))
    let rSI2 = 100 - (100 / (relativeStrength2 + 1))

    // Relative Strength Index Average
    let rsiAverage = (rSI1 + rSI2) / 2

    return rsiAverage
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Martin I couldn't ask for a better explanation! I am getting an error that I don't understand tho `Value of type 'Data' has no member 'close'` at `let diff = now.close - prev.close`

Comment: @Wizzardzz: I assumed that your `data` array has elements of type `struct Data { var close: Double }`.

Comment: I added the struct to the code

Comment: I fixed that by renaming `Level` to `Data`. I have one last error tho, `Use of unresolved identifier 'calculateRSI'` at `let otherObject = calculateRSI()`

Comment: I solved it by simply changing `let diff =  data[idx + 1].close - data[idx].close` to `let diff =  items.data[idx + 1].close - items.data[idx].close`. Thanks again for your help Martin!